# save a split dataset in .txt format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to spit a dataset to `train` and `test`, and then need to save it as in `.txt` format.

Here's the code so far ,

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

category=pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8')

train, test = train_test_split(category, test_size=0.2)

test.to_csv('checkme.txt')
```

However, when I try to do so, it gives the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "splitter.py", line 8, in 
>       test.to_csv('checkme.tsv')
>     File "/home/abc/micro/micro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1745, in to_csv
>       formatter.save()
>     File "/home/abc/micro/micro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 171, in save
>       self._save()
>     File "/home/abc/micro/micro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 286, in _save
>       self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
>     File "/home/abc/micro/micro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 313, in _save_chunk
>       self.cols, self.writer)
>     File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 64, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u026a' in position 111: ordinal not in range(128)

What is possibly wrong here, and how to fix this?

Comment: May wanna specify encoding on `to_csv` as well?

Comment: @RafaelC , yeah need to specify encoding as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your dataframe as unicode:

```
test.to_csv('checkme.txt', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: can you also add sep='\t' , to that, so I can close the question by accepting it as an answer!